# TextBox.Text returned empty after postback from nested asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, nested, updatepanel, postback

This is the code that I have:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPnlParent" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div><h3>title</h3></div>
             <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPnlChild" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                   <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Tb1"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Btn1" Text="Create" OnClick="Create" />
                   </ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code behind I have a function for an event "Create"

```
protected void Create(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textFromPostBack= Tb1.Text;
        //do something...
    }
```

The string is empty.
Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the button as a trigger to the update panel if you want it to trigger a post back:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ...>
    <ContentTemplate>
        blablabla
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Btn1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

More details :[Click](http://forums.asp.net/t/1925881.aspx?Unable%20to%20update%20and%20retrieve%20error%20messages%20if%20I%20would%20nested%20my%20gridview%20inside%20of%20UpdatePanel%20)

Comment: I never really understood why is that, The Button is one of the UpdatePanel's children, so unless I change the Attribute ChildrenAsTriggers to "False" it should be the same, no?

Comment: And It didn't work, it's still empty.
On which <Triggers> should I add it?